# Execute Initiating Statements After Connection Is Acquired

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, c3p0

I'm using Spring JDBC + C3P0. I want to set the 'sql_mode' variable to empty string ''.

First I tried to set it in JDBC url:

```
DataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(
    "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/test?sessionVariables=sql_mode=''",
    "root", "password");
```

But it's not working.

So I'm wondering whether there's a way to execute some statements right after the connection is acquired, such as "SET sql_mode=''".

Thanks.

Comment: adding to samlewis' suggestion below, if all you want is some initialization sql, you can use an already implemented ConnectionCustomizer, and add your initialization SQL to your configuration. Please see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#user_extensions_to_configurations and https://github.com/swaldman/c3p0/blob/master/src/java/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/example/InitSqlConnectionCustomizer.java This is a recent addition to the library, if you want thus, please use c3p0-0.9.5-pre5 or above.

Comment: @SteveWaldman It seems that this customizer supports only one sql?

Comment: yes. it's intended mostly as an example of working with user-defined configuration extensions (and also as a way to deflect annoyance when people complain of the lack of an initSql config, which some pools offer and is sometimes requested). it'd be easy to modify to split on semicolons. alternatively, i could try to add support for compound keys so you could define initSql.statement1, initSql.statement2, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a `ConnectionCustomizer` with C3P0: http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers

```
public class MyConnectionCustomizer extends AbstractConnectionCustomizer {

  public void onCheckOut( Connection c, String parentDataSourceIdentityToken ) { 
    //Run your statements here 
  }
{
```